# get Map data from Firestore

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

i have a localStorage array with the objects. Then i add() this array to firestore.in result i have a document like this [firestore document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9WWC.png)
i have 2 Maps here. So how i can get it to display. when i use this code, i can display only timestamp

```html
this.sells = this.sellsCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(
        changes => {
          return changes.map(a => {
            const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Sell
            const id = a.payload.doc.id;
            return data
          })
        }
      )
    )
```

i can view all the data when i use | json pipe. but cant see Map data with interpolation

**UPD:**
[console log of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2XmM.png)

Comment: Show your template code.

Comment: its simple:    first one shows all data in json <div *ngFor="let sell of sells">
        {{sell | json}} 
    </div> 
 ----second shows only date:
   <div *ngFor="let sell of sells">
        {{sell.items}}, {{sell.date.seconds*1000 | date:"dd-mm-yyyy"}}
    </div>     sell.items is an array with this items in my interface

Comment: The firestore image you've posted doesn't seem to have an `items` property. You should be able to access `sell.stock`, `sell.price` etc... Or, maybe, except for the `date` the other properties would be indexed by a number (in an array like style). I'll try to write an answer so you try it.

Comment: ok, i tried sell.stock end other properties, but got nothing. still date field displayed only

Comment: Look at my answer and give it a try.

Comment: if it doesn't work I'd ask you to console.log what is arriving from the firestore (the array of `a.payload.doc.data()`) so we can better analyze it.

Comment: your example gives an error msg: @Cannot find name 'key'. i added a picture of console log of data()

Comment: Oh, sorry. I had a typo in my answer in the filter function. Try it again.

Comment: oh, that looks better! now i have [object Object],[object Object] - when i write {{sell.items}}. so if i need get some fields, i need to turn to them like sell.items.stock for example? but then i get nothing

Comment: Almost that... each `sell` has an array of `items`. Take a look at my answer again, as I modified it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your `map` observable operator:

```
changes => {
  return changes.map(a => {
      const temp = a.payload.doc.data() as Sell

      // Each temp has the following shape (it looks like an array
      //   but it isn't really one. It's a more general object that
      //   is not an iterable out-of-the-box):
      // {
      //   1:    {...},
      //   2:    {...},
      //   3:    {...},
      //   ...
      //   date: '...'
      // }
      // We want to convert this object, to another object
      //   with the following shape: {items: any[], date: string}
      // To do that, what we can do is iterate over all of the keys
      //   of the incoming object (shown above) except for the 'date' 
      //   key and put all of their values in the items array. 
      // We can do that by getting all of the keys as an array
      //   (Object.keys) and iterate through them, filtering out the
      //   'date' key. For the other keys, that actually pass by the
      //   filter, we use the map function to turn them into their actual
      //   values.
      const items = Object.keys(temp)
          .filter(key => key !== 'date')
          .map(key => temp[key]);

      // Now we just have to build up the object to be returned, including
      //   the date, that was filtered out in the code above.
      return {items, date: temp.date};
    }) // end of Array.map
}
```

Then, in your template ou can do:

```html
<div *ngFor="let sell of sells">
  <div *ngFor"let item of sell?.items">
    {{item?.stock}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry, last question. i want to understand rightly what is going on in .ts . so in const items we put all the fields of our document. then, with filter, we get all the fields that are not equal to date - that is our items. and what is going on in .map?

Comment: Commented above, in the answer.